# Manually trigger OK_OPTION for a JOptionPane within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane

I've got some utility code that presents a `JList` inside a `JPanel` that is used inside a `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`, similar to this:

```java
SelectionPanel<T> panel = new SelectionPanel<>(allValues, initiallySelectedElement, multipleSelection);
int action = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parent, panel, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
if (action == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This works well, but I've had a feature request to be able to double click in the list to add the clicked element. The panel has no knowledge of being wrapped in a `JOptionPane`, and ideally I would like to keep it that way.

I've found that I can close the dialog using the following code:

```java
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !e.isControlDown()) {
        Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        w.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

However this closes it without `action == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` being `true`.

Is there any generic way of signaling the `OK_OPTION` action and closing, from a `JPanel` that is oblivious to being inside a `JOptionPane`?

Comment: Could the voter (closer) indicate what in particular is unclear?

Comment: Not the voter/closer, but other than having the JPanel call some generic method in the parent component (That you have created/overridden) I can't think of any way to keep it oblivious.

Comment: @sorifiend thanks. I was perhaps hoping that this mechanism (setting the "result") happened through some generic event mechanism that might be present even though the code doesn't itself have access to the parent (wrapper). I have not looked into how it is coded in `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your `mouseClicked` method as following:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && !e.isControlDown()) {
        JOptionPane pane = (JOptionPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JOptionPane.class, e.getComponent());
        pane.setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        w.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will accept as this solves the problem I formulated. Thank you! Having reviewing the desired result I will probably end up rewriting to avoid this "invisible relation" between the `JPanel` and the `JOptionPane`.

Comment: I think, it would be difficult to avoid this "invisible relation". Another possibility to get the JOptionPane is to use `AncestorListener`. But "invisible relation" in this case is still present. And in your solution you already have "invisible relation" to `Window`

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand your editor doesn’t have to know that it is residing in a JOptionPane. Obviously, there must be code putting the editor into an option pane. *That* code can add a listener to the editor to close the option pane. By the way, calling `setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)` on the `JOptionPane` is already sufficient, the option pane will care to close the dialog.

Comment: To stay at your question’s example, instead of `int action = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog( parent, panel, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);` you do `JOptionPane oPane = new JOptionPane(panel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); /* add your listener to panel, to call oPane.setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) */ oPane.createDialog(parent, title).setVisible(true); int action = (int)oPane.getValue();` That’s it. The `SelectionPanel` doesn’t need to know.

Answer (score 2):

The following runnable code *may be* another solution for you: Read the comments in code:

```
public class DoubleClickJListItemToExitDialog {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DoubleClickJListItemToExitDialog().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Temp OptionPane Parent...
        javax.swing.JFrame iFrame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        iFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        iFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        iFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        String selectedItem = null;  // To hold the selected list item String value;
        
        
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();        // Create JPanel
        panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 200));   // Set its size
        
        javax.swing.JLabel msg = new javax.swing.JLabel(            // Create the dialog message
                "<html>Select an item from the list and then select the OK<br>"
                + "button.  If you like,  you can also double-click on the<br>"
                + "item in the list as well to make your selection.<br><br></html>");
        panel.add(msg);     // Add message to panel
        
        // Create a DefaultListModel
        javax.swing.DefaultListModel<String> model = new javax.swing.DefaultListModel<>();
        // Add (whatever) String elements to the Model
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.addElement("List String Item " + (i+1));
        }
        
        // Create a JList and add the DefaultListModel to it.
        javax.swing.JList<String> list = new javax.swing.JList<>(model);
        /* Add a MouseListener to the JList so to pick up Double-Clicks 
           within the mouseClicked event:             */
        list.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                // Was the left mouse button clicked twice
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    // Get the OptionPane...
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane pane = (javax.swing.JOptionPane) 
                            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(
                                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.class, e.getComponent());
                    // Fire the OK Option button
                    pane.setValue(javax.swing.JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                // Not in use here.
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                // Not in use here.
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                // Not in use here.
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                // Not in use here.
            }
        });
        
        // Create a JScrollPane and add the JList to it.
        javax.swing.JScrollPane sp = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(list);
        // Set the desired JScrollPane Size
        sp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(180,120));
        // Add the JScrollPane to the JPanel
        panel.add(sp);
        
        /* Display the JOptionPane Option Dialog using the temp JFrame as parent 
           and the newly created JPanel as its content, the desired title, the
           desired dialog buttons (OK and Cancel), as a Plain Message dialog (no
           icon image).        */
        int res = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(iFrame, panel, 
                "Select From List:", javax.swing.JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        
        // If the dialog's OK button was selected....
        if (res == javax.swing.JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            // Get the selected JList element and store in `selectedItem`:
            selectedItem = list.getSelectedValue();
            // Open a messge dialog to display the selected JList item:
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFrame, 
                    "<html>Selected List Item Was:<br><br><center><font size='5' color=blue><b>" 
                    + selectedItem + "</b></font></center><br></html>", "Your Selection", 
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        iFrame.dispose();  // Dispose of the temp JFrame Parent.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think my biggest take from this is that I don't have to do `getWindowAncestor`, since setting the value will will fire the property change event, which in the `JOptionPane` case closes the window by itself.